# A variable, Multiple Checkbox Select/Deselect using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, checkbox

I found [this code](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/multiple-checkbox-select-deselect-jquery-tutorial-example/#comments) to make something have multiple checkbox select/deselect. The code itself works fine but I want it be able to take in a variable so I do not need to write it 20 times in my script.

What it looks like now:

```
$(function(){

// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#selectcase").click(function () {
      $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(".case").click(function(){

    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectcase").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectcase").removeAttr("checked");
    }

});
```

What I want to take in:

```
function locatebox(x){
console.log(x);
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
$("#select" + x).click(function(x) {
      $("." + x ).attr("checked", this.checked);
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$("." + x ).click(function(x){

    if($("." + x).length == $("." + x + ":checked").length) {
        $("#select" + x ).attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#select" + x).removeAttr("checked");
    }
});
//locatebox("rase");
}
locatebox("rase");
```

When I look in the executed code It shows that rase function has been generated but it does not check any boxes.

Thank you to anyone that could possibly help me out.

## Edit: I for got to show how I call it and what the check-box values will be.

I do not know if this is the correct to call out the JavaScript.

Call the multi-select check-box:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" id="selectrase" onclick="locatebox('rase');"/></td>
```

Defining one check box:

```
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="rase" name="rase" value="3"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="rase" name="rase" value="4"/></td>
```

Thank you once again.

Comment: Remove the `x` argument in the handlers. An [Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) object is passed. Not the 'x' parameter to `locatebox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your architecture for this is just fundamentally flawed.  Using `onclick()` and jQuery makes for insanely hard debugging.  With jQuery you should be using [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).  Take advantage of classes and the data attribute to target other elements.

Instead consider:

```js
// Wait for the document to load
$(document).ready(function(){
  // for all elements that have this class watch for clicks
  $('.js-checkbox-group-toggle').on('click', function(){
    // create jquery object of what was clicked
    var $this = $(this);
    // find the selector target for what was clicked;
    var target = $this.data('group-target');
    // find all the selector targets
    var $targets = $(target);
    // assign all the targets the value of what was clicked
    $targets.prop("checked", $this.prop("checked"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" class="js-checkbox-group-toggle" data-group-target=".group1" />Targets Group 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="js-checkbox-group-toggle" data-group-target=".group2" />Targets Group 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" />Hello 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="group2" />Hello 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" />Test 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="group2" />Test 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="group2" />English 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="group1" />Breakfast 1<br />
```

Add as MANY of these as you want, you have no variables in JS to mess with and the code base never has to change.

Comment: Thank you this works great. The only thing that it does not do is that it does not uncheck the Targets Group 1 check-box if you deselect one of the group on boxes.

Comment: This is just a proof of concept.  You can make it do whatever you want if you understand how this code works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<td><input type="checkbox" id="selectrase" /></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="rase" name="rase" value="3"/></td>
<td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="rase" name="rase" value="4"/></td>
...

<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function locatebox(x){
console.log(x);
// add multiple select / deselect functionality
var id = "#select" + x;
var className = '.' + x;

$(id).click(function(x) {
      $(className).prop("checked", $(id).is(':checked'));
});

// if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
// and viceversa
$(className).click(function(){

      $(id).prop("checked", ($(className).length == $(className + ":checked").length));

   });

}

$(document).ready(function(){
    locatebox("rase");
}) ; 
//--></script>
```

Comment: I ran your code and it gives me this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).prop is not a function` for line 77 or `$(className).prop("checked", $(id).is(':checked'));` this line exactly.

Comment: which version of jQuery you use?